# Install Visual Studio Code extensions without NPM installed

Tags: javascript, npm, visual-studio-code

I have all my development environments with Docker and NPM install inside containers. How can I install js extensions like jshint in Visual Studio Code without having NPM installed on my machine?

Comment: You can install `yarn` alternatively.

Comment: Why you don't want to install npm?